# How to describe regression interaction terms in compact form?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have regressors `a`, `b`, `c`, `e_1` and `e_2` and I want to run the following regression:

`y ~ a + b + c + e_1 + e_2 + a.e_1 + a.e_2 + b.e_1 + b.e_2 + c.e_1 + c.e_2`

Each of the `e_1` and `e_2` has to interact with `a`, `b` and `c` variables.

I actually have 5 `e`'s and 5 other variables. What would be the quickest way to write the code instead of writing individually `a:e_1`, `a:e_2` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `~(a+b+c)*(e1+e2)` ?

Example:

```
dd <- data.frame(a=1,b=1,c=1,e1=1,e2=1)
colnames(model.matrix(~(a+b+c)*(e1+e2),dd)
##  [1] "(Intercept)" "a"           "b"           "c"           "e1"         
##  [6] "e2"          "a:e1"        "a:e2"        "b:e1"        "b:e2"       
## [11] "c:e1"        "c:e2"
```

For a larger set of variables, an alternative to @ThomasIsCoding's solution:

```
pfun <- function(x) paste("(", paste(x,collapse="+"), ")")
reformulate(paste(pfun(p), "*", pfun(q)), response="y")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was very helpful.

Comment: The sentiment is appreciated, but SO actually deprecates "thank-you" comments.  If these answers solved your problem, please pick the one you think is best and click on the check-mark to accept it ..

Answer (score 1):

If you have know the grouped names of variables for interactive parts in the formula, like `p` and `q` below

```
p <- c("a","b","c")
q <- c("e_1","e_2")
```

you can try the following code to generate the whole formula using `as.formula` and `paste0`, i.e.,

```
f <- as.formula(paste0("y ~",paste0(c(p,q,do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(p,q),sep = ":"))),collapse = "+")))
```

such that

```
> f
y ~ a + b + c + e_1 + e_2 + a:e_1 + b:e_1 + c:e_1 + a:e_2 + b:e_2 + 
    c:e_2
```

and

```
> class(f)
[1] "formula"
```